# Como colocar trecho de código dentro de site wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Olá, quero colocar uns posts sobre Php dentro de um site gerenciado por Wordpress, como faço para colocar aqueles trechos de código que ficam já formatados, não quero eu ter que formatar toda hora.

[image: Para ficar tipo assim]

Comment: Coloquei outra imagem, é em um fórum, onde é possível colocar o trecho do código, pode ver que esta cinza, esta bem simples, já vi uns mais complexos, parecia que tinha um sublime text dentro do site.
O que eu não quero é colocar prints ou ter que escrever trechos de código e ficarem sem formatação.

Comment: O nome disso em inglês é Syntax Highlight: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Syntax+Highlight/

Comment: Isso, não sabia como procurar, vlw !